# valueChanged event listener java swing = why double clicked?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I got little problem, with selecting item from JList.
I use valueChanged ListSelectionListener but when i select any item it is clicked twice and i need it to be clicked only once. Are there any other action listeners which can do it?

this problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D496F.jpg]

Full code there: https://pastebin.ca/4029336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

You need to check the `getValueIsAdjusting()` method of the `ListSelectionEvent` and only do your processing when the value returns false.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. It wasn't easy to realize that ;p

Comment: @Hubert, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: All right. I'm using this forum properly now :d have nice evening mate.